# Skype & Terminal Services information exchange?

Tags: windows, macos, skype, terminal-services

We have sales reps who access our 'system' via terminal services.  In our system we would like to enable clicking the number of a client and launching skype on their local machine not in the terminal services session.

We see two potential ways of this working...

1. Clicking on a URL ( eg skype:01234569?call ) and it works locally but we need to click the url in the TS session but having that url opened on the local computer.
2. Or something like skype@IP_address:01234569?call to make a target skype client make the call?

One last thing, the local machine might be a Mac or Windows PC.

Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 would not work at all!

Option 2 sounds interesting but you might get definite answers from https://developers.skype.com or http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showforum=16